# SQL Case expression when execute

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I would like to update one cell when execute certain update on a table.
I have the following possible states:

- First state: ***state_1*** or ***NULL***
- Second state: ***state_2***
- Third state: ***state_3***
- Fourth state: ***state_4***

And this is the query that is not executed:

```
UPDATE `status`
SET `state` = (CASE
    WHEN `state` = 'state_1' or NULL THEN 'state_2'
    WHEN `state` = 'state_2' THEN 'state_3'
    ELSE 'state_4'
END;)
WHERE `id` = '1';
```

What's the problem or how can I resolve this situation? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `status`
SET `state` = CASE WHEN `state` = 'state_1' or `state` is NULL THEN 'state_2'
                    WHEN `state` = 'state_2' THEN 'state_3'
                    ELSE 'state_4'
               END
WHERE `id` = '1';
```